# version of golang.org/x/sys@hash in go.mod ignored

Tags: go, go-modules

I am trying to use `github.com/docker/engine` as a dependency for [dockmoor](https://github.com/MeneDev/dockmoor/tree/develop), however, there were [breaking changes](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34610) in `x/sys/windows` and so compiling for windows is not working anymore.

```
##[error]/home/runner/go/pkg/mod/github.com/docker/engine@v0.0.0-20200204220554-5f6d6f3f2203/pkg/system/filesys_windows.go:111:24:
cannot use uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&sd[0])) (type uintptr) as type *"golang.org/x/sys/windows".SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR in assignment
```

I tried to set an explicit version of `golang.org/x/sys` using for example

`go get -u golang.org/x/sys@acfa387b8d69adbeab4af0736737d42b9f2e8254`

I can see the version reflected in my `go.mod`, yet

`GO111MODULE=on GOOS=windows go build ./cmd/dockmoor`

results in the same error.

I also tried different revisions, like `14da1ac737ccc89e3a28bf770cbbd260ce7e190b` which is the parent of the change, but I always get that error.

It seems like the version of `golang.org/x/sys` is just ignored.

For my last try I had:
moby/engine v19.03.6 / v0.0.0-20200204220554-5f6d6f3f2203
go version: 1.12.16 (same as used in moby/engine v19.03.6)
golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20190602015325-4c4f7f33c9ed (same as used in moby/engine v19.03.6)

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You can't import multiple versions of the same package, so perhaps you have a dependency that requires a more recent release?

Comment: Oh, I think your right. I had to explicitly override /x/sys, thanks for the pointer, I wrongly assumed the version I explicitly declared would either be used or cause an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some dependencies pulled in another version of `golang.org/x/sys`

The solution was to add an explicit override at the end of `go.mod`. In my case it looks like this

```
replace golang.org/x/sys => golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20190830141801-acfa387b8d69
```

Comment: i tried to do this but still get the sam error.
And in the file filesys_windows.go it highlights the error in line  112
sa.SecurityDescriptor = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&sd[0]))